# How to make player stay on a moving object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player falls from a moving car when stands on the top of it.

Player uses character controller to move.

Car uses rigidbody to move.

i tried this code but its not helping

```
public GameObject myPlayer;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
{
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Truck")
    {
        myPlayer.transform.parent = myPlayer.gameObject.transform;
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider coll)
{
        myPlayer.transform.parent = null;
}
```

}

all the tags are checked and on their place

thanks
Seit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
myPlayer.transform.parent = myPlayer.gameObject.transform;
```

You are parenting your player's transform to your player's transform itself instead of the truck's transform.

correct code:

```
myPlayer.transform.parent = coll.gameObject.transform;
```

Comment: its working but my player with truck starting to shake and fall on other sides, how to fix it?

Comment: oh bruh the problem was in my player movement script bcs its moved w character controller and truck w rigidbody. I fully changed my player movement script and connected it w rigidbody and everything started to work.

Comment: Aah, happens to the best of us, happy for you.